# jquery ui draggable connectToSortable how to stop fade Animation on drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Does anybody know how I can delete the fading effect after dropping or sorting an element at the following example?

[Jquery sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `revert` tags:
http://jsfiddle.net/UnHPn/`

For completeness:

> **revert**
>
> Boolean, String Default:false
>
> If set to true, the element will return to its start position when
>   dragging stops. Possible string values: 'valid', 'invalid'. If set to
>   invalid, revert will only occur if the draggable has not been dropped
>   on a droppable. For valid, it's the other way around.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-revert

Comment: oh yes, perfect, i forgot to remove the revert tag for the sortable. :-/